# Downloading buildings data from OSM with a polygon (shapefile) as the bounding box

Tags: python, polygon, openstreetmap, geopandas, osmnx

I am struggling to complete this task. I am trying OSMnx which can be used to download data from OSM above however I am getting an error when using its `from_polygon` feature when trying to download data. Also, I am not sure if this data will include Buildings data.

I load my shapefile into geopandas and can then view and interact with it

This is the code

```
Building_data = ox.graph_from_polygon(my_shapefile, network_type='all')
ox.plot_graph(Building_data)
```

However, I am getting this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

EDIT: I managed to convert the shapefile into a shapely polygon and run the OSMnx script again,

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
import fiona
c = fiona.open('E:/shapefile.shp')
pol = c.next()
geom = shape(pol['geometry'])

import osmnx as ox
data = ox.graph_from_polygon(geom, network_type='all')
ox.plot_graph(data)
```

however, now I get this CRS error:

```
Invalid projection: +proj=utm +zone=80957 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: Error -35 (invalid UTM zone number)).
```

It seems a shapely polygon has no CRS or the wrong CRS.

Comment: Your code snippet isn't reproducible (as the critical input file is missing). It will be easier to answer your question if you provide a minimal complete reproducible code snippet and the full error traceback.

Comment: UTM zones like this are EPSG UTM codes start with 326 or 327. 80957 is not understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to download buildings data from OSM with a polygon (shapefile) as the bounding box however I was able to using distance from a point with the following code:

```
import osmnx as ox 
import ast

point = 'point coordinates'
dist = 'distance in m'
buildings = ox.geometries.geometries_from_point(point, {'building': True}, dist=dist)
```

And convert to a geodataframe:

```
buildings_save = buildings.applymap(lambda x: str(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
```

Then I clip the buildings data to a boundary using geopandas:

```
import geopandas as gpd

boundary = gpd.read_file('C:/boundary.shp')
buildings_final = gpd.clip(buildings_save, boundary)
```

Plot the data to check:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,12))
buildings_final.plot(ax = ax, color = 'red', edgecolor = 'black',)
plt.title('Buildings Data')
plt.show()
```